# Can't use indexable type with parenthesis

Tags: typescript

```
// EX 1
interface Animal {
  [dwdwdwd: number]: string;
}
let myArr : Animal = ["Joy", "Joy2"];

console.log("EX1 : " + myArr[1]); // Joy2

// EX 2
interface States {
    [state: string]: boolean;
}
let myArr2: States = {'enabled': true, 'maximized':false};
console.log("EX2 : " + myArr2['maximized']); // false

// EX 3
interface Animal2 {
  (props: { [key: string]: any }): boolean;
}

const test = {props : {'enabled':false}}; // I don't think this is correct of putting variable

let myArr3 : Animal2 = test; // compile error
```

I want to make make EX 3 so that it utilizes "interface Animal2", but I do not know how to utilize it like the way shown in EX1 and EX2.

Can anyone provide me an example of the use of EX3? and console.log any variable of it.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you're trying to create an interface for a function:

```
interface Animal2 {
    (props: {[key: string]: any}): boolean;
}

let isPeterPan: Animal2 = (props: {name: string, lastName: string}) => props.name === "peter" && props.lastName === "pan";

console.log(isPeterPan({name: "peter", lastName: "parker"})); // false
console.log(isPeterPan({name: "peter", lastName: "pan"})); // true
```

Comment: Sorry, I get this error:
Type '(props: {    age: number;}) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'Animal2'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Property 'age' is missing in type '{ [key: string]: any; }' but required in type '{ age: number; }'.(2322)
input.tsx(5, 39): 'age' is declared here.

Comment: sorry, you were right, I had changed the example to make it easier and didn't run it again. I updated the response ...

Comment: Thank you very much. I think your example is correct usage but i still get error on playground: Type '(props: {    name: string;    lastName: string;}) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'Animal2'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type '{ [key: string]: any; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ name: string; lastName: string; }': name, lastName

Comment: It's weird because I see the error in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play but it allows me to run the code and it works as we expect. Also, I compile the code locally without problem. Could you try it in other place?

Comment: check this: https://codepen.io/codezisland/pen/RwrQoOd